# Cell Selected should display message which is on a cell on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Excel VBA so please be patient with me. Thanks.

I have 2 sheets in my workbook. Sheet1 and Sheet2 both has same number of rows. I have a column named as SITE in Sheet2 and REMARK named on Sheet1. What I need is whenever I select the cell in SITE column ,it should display a message(i.e; message should contain cell value of REMARK column) from the Sheet1.

For example: If SITE column-cell 3 is selected then message displayed should contain value of REMARK column-cell 3.

Comment: By a "message", do you mean a message box (with an "OK" or "Cancel")? Or just some type of message showing the remark value?  If the former, you'll want to look into `MsgBox()` in VBA, and [`Worksheet_SelectionChange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194470.aspx) event.  Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I haven't write anything yet. Just a message like in data validation. I don't need OK and Cancel. Just the message or note showing REMARK value.

Answer (score 2):

because I'm bored:

```
'in Sheet1
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column = Application.Match("SITE", Target.Parent.Rows(1), 0) Then MsgBox Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Target.Row, Application.Match("REMARK", Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(1), 0)).Value2
End Sub

'in Sheet2
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column = Application.Match("REMARK", Target.Parent.Rows(1), 0) Then MsgBox Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Target.Row, Application.Match("SITE", Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(1), 0)).Value2
End Sub
```

**EDIT**
your "...SITE column..." in the question said me that the headers are at row 1... but if you know where they are, and the pos is not changing, then you can use it like this (I assume that the first value for "SITE" is in P8 and the first "REMARK" at Q9 to show how to offset):

```
'in Sheet1
'the "Target.Row + 1" need the row offset because it starts 1 row later
'if they start at the same row, the "+ 1" can be deleted
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column = Range("P1").Column And Target.Row >= 8 Then MsgBox Sheets("Sheet2").Range("Q" & Target.Row + 1).Value2
End Sub

'---------------------------------------------------------------------

'in Sheet2
'because the offset must be the opposite, the "+ 1" becomes "- 1" here
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column = Range("Q1").Column And Target.Row >= 9 Then MsgBox Sheets("Sheet1").Range("P" & Target.Row - 1).Value2
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried your code and it is showing me error "type mismatch". The SITE column name is written at position P8. Do I have to mention SITE in the code or something like P8?

Comment: I mean the excel column names are starting from row 8 and the other top 7 rows have some headings/information regarding the sheet..

Comment: please see my edit... if the cell-location may change in row and column, you would need to go with either more information or use `Range.Find` which may error out if there are multiple cells which contain "SITE" and/or "Remark"...

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I have tried the code but it is doing nothing. There is no error but there is no message also.